# Make the loop run after "return" statement. [React JS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Aim: I want to render 64 `<Square />` elements with `<br/>` after each 8 elements

Problem: The script outputs just one block and then stops and nothing more happens.

Source Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div id="block"></div>;
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
      if (i % 8 == 0) {
        return <br />;
      } else {
        return <Square />;
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderSquare()}</div>;
  }
}

function Game() {
  return (
    <div id="board">
      <Board />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: that's what return does - it `return`s a value from a function - your attempt would only output 56 `<Square>` even if you could return like that anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using return statement will exit the function after first match, hence in first loop it exits and only displays 1st element, you need to use an array, store the elements in it, and then return the array.

Change your `renderSquare` method to following

```
renderSquare() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        if (i % 8 === 0) {
            items.push(<br />);
        } else {
            items.push(<Square />);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

**Update**

if you want to print  64 times then use the following

```
renderSquare() {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        items.push(<Square />);
        if (i % 8 === 0) {
            items.push(<br />);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-brattain-pj32le?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this code still has an logical error that `<Square />` doesn't appear 64 times.

Comment: Updated the code to print `<Square>` 64 times